# Person lookup in Excel metadata field crashes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, excel, metadata

I have `SharePoint 2013 Foundation` and I open `Excel 2013` from `Document Library`, which has serval metadata fields, including `Person Lookup`.

Now, when I press `Address book` icon at Excel metadata bar, program just crashes:

[[image: Address book icon press[1]]

After I  click this Address book (or check name), Excel just crashes...
[image: Excel crashes]

Any suggestions, what might be the problem? Event log doesn't show anything useful neither.

I personally think, that this might be a problem with communication with SharePoint or some features are blocked, but what I should look for, if this might be the problem?

Comment: Could this problem happen because of some closed ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason of my problem, that caused Excel to crash, when selecting People Lookup button. When I encountered same problem with `SharePoint Designer` `User Lookup from site`, I started to investigate it further.

Cause of problem was, that there were two port `80 bindings` in `IIS` with different host names. Had to remove one (not defined in Central Admin) and have only one port `80 binding`. After that, it worked fine.